# Accidentally deleted workspaces

Tags: workspaces, ubuntu-studio

I deleted my workspaces in Ubuntu studio, now I want to have them again.
Didn't find any answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it by using **Compiz** >> **General Options**, Right?

Comment: Can be done easier: desktop, rightclick, appearances. the 2nd tab has a checkbox ;)

Comment: Ya but He is asking abt Ubuntu Studio so I recommended Compiz. :)